# How to track number of distinct values incrementally from a spark table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-processing, incremental-search

Suppose we have a very large table that we'd like to process statistics for incrementally.

| Date | Amount | Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 | 30 | Mary |
| 2022-12-21 | 12 | Mary |
| 2022-12-20 | 12 | Bob |
| 2022-12-21 | 15 | Bob |
| 2022-12-22 | 15 | Alice |

We'd like to be able to calculate incrementally how much we made per distinct customer for a date range. So from 12-20 to 12-22 (inclusive), we'd have 3 distinct customers, but 12-20 to 12-21 there are 2 distinct customers.

If we want to run this pipeline once a day and there are many customers, how can we keep a rolling count of distinct customers for an arbitrary date range? Is there a way to do this without storing a huge list of customer names for each day?

We'd like to support a frontend that has a date range filter and can quickly calculate results for that date range. For example:

| Start Date | End Date | Average Income Per Customer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-21 | (30+12+12+15)/2 = 34.5 |
| 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-22 | (30+12+12+15+15)/3 = 28 |

The only approach I can think of is to store a set of customer names for each day, and when viewing the results calculate the size of the joined set of sets to calculate distinct customers. This seems inefficient. In this case we'd store the following table, with the customer column being extremely large.

| Date | Total Income | Customers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-20 | 42 | set(Mary, Bob) |
| 2022-12-21 | 27 | set(Mary, Bob) |
| 2022-12-22 | 15 | set(Alice) |

Comment: Vague. Post the example output with more input.

Comment: @thebluephantom updated with more info for how the stats will be used. thanks!

Comment: Do you need the actual names of the users? Or do you simply need to know the count? Also, do you mind if it is an estimate on the number of user vs an exact count?

Comment: @marios do not need actual names, and an estimate of distinct count is sufficient.

Comment: Spark-alchemy has a data structure called HLL that will help you keep a running approximate sketch https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/hyperloglog-count-distinct/

Comment: The hll function together with a windowing function should get you what you need.

Comment: @marios that article was super helpful, thanks a lot for linking it. if you want to put it as an answer I can accept it. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the best solution is to do some pre calculations for the existing data, then for the new data that come everyday, do the caclulation only on new data, and add the results to the previous calclulated data, also do partitioning on date column as we filter on dates, this will trigger spark push down filters and accelerate your queries.

There's 2 approach: one to get the sum amount between 2 dates, and other for the distinct customers between 2 dates:

- For amout use prefix sum by adding the sum of all previous days to the last day, then to get the difference between the 2 dates you can just substract these 2 days only without looping all dates between.

For distinct customers, the best approach I can think of is to save the date and customer columns in a new file, and partition by dates, that would help to optimize the queries, then use the fast approx_count_distinct.

Here's some code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ["2022-12-20", 30, "Mary"],
    ["2022-12-21", 12, "Mary"],
    ["2022-12-20", 12, "Bob"],
    ["2022-12-21", 15, "Bob"],
    ["2022-12-22", 15, "Alice"],
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("Date", "Amount", "Customer")

def init_amout_data(df):
    w = Window.orderBy(col("Date"))
    amount_sum_df = df.groupby("Date").agg(sum("Amount").alias("Amount")) \
        .withColumn("amout_sum", sum(col("Amount")).over(w)) \
        .withColumn("prev_amout_sum", lag("amout_sum", 1, 0).over(w)).select("Date", "amout_sum", "prev_amout_sum")
    amount_sum_df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Date").parquet("./path/amount_data_df")
    amount_sum_df.show(truncate=False)

# keep only customer data to avoid unecessary data when querying, partitioning by Date will make query faster due to spark filter push down mechanism
def init_customers_data(df):
    df.select("Date", "Customer").write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Date").parquet("./path/customers_data_df")

# each day update the amount data dataframe (example at midnight), with only yesterday data: by talking the last amout_sum and adding to it the amount of the last day
def update_amount_data(last_partition):
    amountDataDf = spark.read.parquet("./path/amount_data_df")
    maxDate = getMaxDate("./path/amount_data_df")  # implement a hadoop method to get the last partition date
    lastMaxPartition = amountDataDf.filter(col("date") == maxDate)
    lastPartitionAmountSum = lastMaxPartition.select("amout_sum").first.getLong(0)
    yesterday_amount_sum = last_partition.groupby("Date").agg(sum("Amount").alias("amount_sum"))
    newPartition = yesterday_amount_sum.withColumn("amount_sum", col("amount_sum") + lastPartitionAmountSum) \
        .withColumn("prev_amout_sum", lit(lastPartitionAmountSum))
    newPartition.write.mode("append").partitionBy("Date").parquet("./path/amount_data_df")

def update_cusomers_data(last_partition):
    last_partition.write.mode("append").partitionBy("Date").parquet("./path/customers_data_df")

def query_amount_date(beginDate, endDate):
    amountDataDf = spark.read.parquet("./path/amount_data_df")
    endDateAmount = amountDataDf.filter(col("Date") == endDate).select("amout_sum").first.getLong(0)
    beginDateDf = amountDataDf.filter(col("Date") == beginDate).select("prev_amout_sum").first.getLong(0)
    diff_amount = endDateAmount - beginDateDf
    return diff_amount

def query_customers_date(beginDate, endDate):
    customersDataDf = spark.read.parquet("./path/customers_data_df")
    distinct_customers_nb = customersDataDf.filter(col("date").between(lit(beginDate), lit(endDate))) \
        .agg(approx_count_distinct(df.Customer).alias('distinct_customers')).first.getLong(0)
    return distinct_customers_nb

# This is should be executed the first time only
init_amout_data(df)
init_customers_data(df)
# This is should be executed everyday at midnight with data of the last day only
last_day_partition = df.filter(col("date") == yesterday_date)
update_amount_data(last_day_partition)
update_cusomers_data(last_day_partition)
# Optimized queries that should be executed with
beginDate = "2022-12-20"
endDate = "2022-12-22"
answer = query_amount_date(beginDate, endDate) / query_customers_date(beginDate, endDate)
print(answer)
```

If calculating the distinct customer is not fast enough, there's another approach using the same pre sum calculation of all distinct customers and another table for distinct customer, each day if there's a new customer increment the first table and add that customer to the second table, if not don't do anything.

Finally there are some tricks for optimizing the goupBy or window functions using salting oo extended partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by filtering rows with dates between start_date and end_date then grouping by customer_id and calculating the sum of amounts and then getting avg of these amounts. this approach works for only one start_date and end_date and you should run this code with different parameters to solve with different date ranges

```
start_date = '2022-12-20'
end_date = '2022-12-21'
(
    df
    .withColumn('isInRange', F.col('date').between(start_date, end_date))
    .filter(F.col('isInRange'))
    .groupby('customer')
    .agg(F.sum('amount').alias('sum'))
    .agg(F.avg('sum').alias('avg income'))
).show()
```